# Is it possible to import more than one module in main.ts in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, module

Generally in Angular 2 the `main.ts` file contains *only one* module which is generally *AppComponent* by `import {AppComponent} from "./app.component"`

Is it possible to import more than one module in the `main.ts` file?

Comment: no you cant import multiple modules here

Comment: @anshuVersatile: thanks